# Find all real solutions to $[x]+[2x]+[4x]+[8x]+[16x]+[32x]=12345$

Tags: real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find all real solutions of the equation:

$$[x]+[2x]+[4x]+[8x]+[16x]+[32x]=12345$$
Where $[.]$ is greatest integer fuction.

Comment: "Greatest integer" what?

Comment: @barakmanos You know, the floor function? Greatest integer less than or equal to its argument.

Comment: Using floor function this has no solutions. Using ceiling function it does.

Comment: @barakmanos look: http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/spoken/here/1words/g/g6.htm

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Write $x$ in binary as $n + 0.b_1b_2b_3b_4b_5b_6\ldots$, where $b_i \in \{0,1\}$ are binary digits, and $n$ is an integer. You should be able to compute the expression, and it should only depend on $n, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5$. Then set it equal to $12345$.